# PayPal v.zero multi-currency support

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree, express-checkout

I'm writing a system that uses PayPals Express Checkout with the v.zero API. The issue I'm having is that it will only accept payments in USD, however I need to to accept USD, GBP, AUD and EUR. I'm processing the transaction as follows:

```
$transaction = array(
    'amount' => $order->cost_total,
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $info->nonce,
    'orderId' => $orderId,
    'descriptor' => array(
        'name' => '-removed-',
    ),
    'shipping' => array(
        'firstName' => $info->firstName,
        'lastName' => $info->lastName,
        'company' => '',
        'streetAddress' => $info->street,
        'extendedAddress' => '',
        'locality' => $info->city,
        'region' => $info->county,
        'postalCode' => $info->postCode,
        'countryCodeAlpha2' => $info->country,
    ),
);
$result = $gateway->transaction()->sale($transaction);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to contact BrainTree to get this added as there are no parameters or account related settings you can pass for currencies.

contact info --> accounts@braintreepayments.com & give them your PayPal email address.